# How can i turn my search method to async?

Tags: c#, wpf

this is my first question on stackoverflow , im junior developer and im working on a project with wpf.

Im still learning mvvm/wpf and ive done many mistakes on the project which im trying to fix. The first mistake is that not all my methods are async. The method im working now is searching on a local db to find msgs between me and a group or someone else, fill an observable list and show it on the view.

```
public void SearchMsg(int MessageLimit, long ClientMsgID, string SearchText = "", bool FirstTime = true, bool loadMore = false)
{

    if (FirstTime == true)
        counter = 0;
    Msgs = new ObservableCollection<Msg>();
    var _msgs = new ObservableCollection<Msg>();

    if (SearchText.Trim() == "") return;

    SQLiteCommand command;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string strSQL;
    string NumberOfRowsQuery;

    command = new SQLiteCommand();
    command.Connection = Globals.Connection;
    command.Parameters.Clear();

    //strSQL = "select msg.companyid, msg.serverid, msg.clientmsgid,msguuid,body,alert,msgtype,destroy,msgdate,scheduleddate, quotemsguuid, account.firstname, account.lastname,msgqid, msgq.fromaccountid, msgq.fromdevid  " +
    strSQL = @"SELECT clientmsgid, msguuid, body from msg where msgtype=0 ";


    if (ClientMsgID != 0)
    {
        //cannot use clientmsgid for paging because you might receive messages to a previous date

        Msg _msg0 = DatabaseMessages.GetMsg(ClientMsgID: ClientMsgID);

        strSQL += " AND clientmsgid < @clientmsgdD ";
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clientmsgdD", ClientMsgID);

        //strSQL += " AND msgdate <= @msgdate  ";
        //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@msgdate", _msg0.MsgDate);

        //strSQL += " AND ClientMsgID <> @clientmsgdD ";
        //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clientmsgdD", ClientMsgID);
    }
    strSQL += "  order by clientmsgid desc limit @limit ";

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@limit", MessageLimit);
    command.CommandText = strSQL;
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    //command.CommandText = strSQL;

    SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand();
    if (FirstTime)
    {
        NumberOfRowsQuery = @" SELECT COUNT(*) from msg where msgtype = 0 ";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clientmsgid", ClientMsgID);
    }
    else
    {
        NumberOfRowsQuery = @" SELECT COUNT(*) from msg where msgtype = 0 and clientmsgid < @clientmsgid ";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clientmsgid", ClientMsgID);
    }

    cmd.Connection = Globals.Connection;
    cmd.CommandText = NumberOfRowsQuery;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    NumberOfRows = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());


    using (SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read() && counter < NumberOfRows) // Don't assume we have any rows.
        {
            counter++;
            String strBody = StringCipher.Decrypt((string)reader["body"], Globals.EncryptionPassword).ToLower();
            ClientMsgID = (long)reader["clientmsgid"];
            if (!strBody.Contains(SearchText.ToLower()))
            {
                continue;
            }

            Msg _m = DatabaseMessages.GetMsg(MsgUUID: (string)reader["msguuid"]);
            _lastMsg = _m.ClientMsgID;

            Account _acc = DatabaseCommon.GetAccount(_m.Header.ToAccountID);
            if (_acc != null)
            {
                _m.ToAccountName = _acc.NiceName;

            }
            if (_m.Header.AccountGroupID > 0)
            {

                Group _group = DatabaseCommon.GetGroup(_m.Header.AccountGroupID);
                Site _site = DatabaseCommon.GetSite(_group.SiteID);
                if (_group != null && _site != null)
                {
                    _m.Header.AccountGroupName = _group.Description;
                    _m.Header.SiteName = _site.Description;
                }
                else
                {
                    _m.Header.SiteName = "";
                    _m.Header.AccountGroupName = "";
                }
            }
            //_msgs.Insert(0, _m);

            if (!_msgs.Any(item => item.MsgUUID == _m.MsgUUID))
            {
                if (_m.Body.Length > 50)
                {
                    _m.Body = _m.Body.Substring(0, 50) + "...";
                }
                // string newStr = _m.Body;
                //_m.Body = "<Run Background='Blue'>" + newStr + "</Run>";
                TextFormated(_m, SearchText);
                _m.Highlight = true;
                _msgs.Insert(0, _m);
                // Msgs.Insert(0, _m);
            }
            //break;
        }
    }

    Msgs = _msgs;

    if (Msgs.Count < 1 && FirstTime == true && counter < NumberOfRows)
    {
        SearchMsg(2500, ClientMsgID, SearchText, false);
    }

    if (Msgs.Count > 0)
    {
        FirstTime = false;
    }


    //if ((Msgs.Count) < (MsgCount + desLength) && tries > 0)
    //{
    //    SearchMsg(500, ClientMsgID, SearchText, tries - 1, desLength - Msgs.Count);
    //}


    Console.WriteLine("done");

}
```

this method returns 1 msg.

i call the same method to give the option to the client to load more msg and this is where async part comes. i want to find a way to make an async search which will respond with all msg with given text but i will serve it one by one to the client.

for instance.
searching the word " hello "
this will bring me one msg, if I press load more msg this should be me every hello work ive seen on chat rooms one by one.

Comment: SQLiteDataReader does not provide an asynchronous API. So there is no chance to execute database access asynchronously. But you can create a generator using `yield`. This enables the caller to iterate over your results using a foreach. `yield` asked you to execute the next search on explicit request by the Enumerator.

Comment: That comment helped a lot, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your method's returning type Task instead of void and wrap your code around Task.Run(() => //your code);

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest case, it's just adding an asynchronous wrapper to your method:

```
    public async void SearchMsgAsync(int MessageLimit, long ClientMsgID, string SearchText = "", bool FirstTime = true, bool loadMore = false)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => SearchMsg(MessageLimit, ClientMsgID, SearchText = "", FirstTime, loadMore));
    }
```

Now you can call the async method SearchMsgAsync without any problems.

I also have several recommendations, tips, including on potential problems.

1. I do not know the regulations adopted in your company, but in general it is advisable to follow the **"Framework Design Guidelines"** and **"Naming Guidelines"**.
   In this case, local variables, including method parameters, are named with lower letters.
2. Judging by the code, this method is in your ViewModel.
   But in MVVM with raw data ViewModel doesn't work.
   Working with real data (Business Logic) is entirely concentrated in Model.
   And even more, you work directly with the database.
   And this is not even the Model level, but even lower - the Repository (Data) level.
   Therefore, as far as I can see, your MVVM structure is very badly broken.
3. You create new collections of type ObservableCollecttion in the method.
   This is pretty weird.
   The whole point of this collection is to observable her.
   And usually it is created once in the "Read Only" property.
   This can potentially lead to problems when you observable to one instance of a collection, but work with another.
4. You want to be asynchronous, that is, the execution is not on the main thread of the application.
   But you change the values bound in the View in this method.
   This can throw exceptions.
   For properties this is unlikely, but for binding collections (and commands) it is almost certainly the case.
5. To work with a database in MVVM, it is much more convenient and easier to use the Entity Framework.

Comment: I expected comments like this and this one really helped me to have a better understanding on MVVM and of course improve my code. Thank you very much